# Possibilities of two Web application under a single URL!

Tags: asp.net

I have two web applications developed using ASP.Net. I like to provide a link in Application A to access the aspx page in Application B. By this i can access this both application using the single URL.

Is it possible? if it is possible then how should i proceed?

Suresh

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify what you're trying to accomplish. This may or not be a good idea, though it would be easier to help you accomplish it if we has some more detail.

Answer (score 3):

A web application by (my) definition has a unique URL.  So, no, you can't really have two separate web applications under a single URL.  However, you can have multiple applications on the same server, within their own separate [virtual directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx).  This way you can have:

http://www.mydomain.com/ApplicationA

and

http://www.mydomain.com/ApplicationB

Answer (score 1):

The ONLY way to do this would be by sending either

1. A different GET query-string to access A or B
2. A different COOKIE indicating whether you want A or B
3. Server Side detection of some other data ( Ie: user IP, user Client String etc )

However, this sounds like a BadIdea™ and it could become a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of doing it this way? Not that there's anything wrong per se, but it has a few flags of something that should be avoided. Perhaps if you clarify your question with your need to share a URL, we can give an answer that will help you, instead of just guessing at your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800.aspx)?